# Deleting white space and merging numbers in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, whitespace

My list is:

```
['1', ' ', '1', '0', ' ', '2', '\n']
```

and it needs to be:

```
[1,10,2]
```

How to do it in python?

Comment: How is this list constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the given data and the wanted result it's pretty safe to assume that the list elements with the spaces divide the numbers. If this is the case the following algorithm will work for other input data too.

Join the list to a full string. Then split the string at the whitespaces. Convert the values of the resulting list to integers.

```
list(map(int, ''.join(['1', ' ', '1', '0', ' ', '2', '\n']).split()))
```

Break it down in parts to see what happens

```
>>> data = ['1', ' ', '1', '0', ' ', '2', '\n']
>>> data = ''.join(data)
>>> data
'1 10 2\n'
>>> data = data.split()
>>> data
['1', '10', '2']
>>> data = list(map(int, data))
>>> data
[1, 10, 2]
```

An example for other input data:

```
>>> list(map(int, ''.join(['1', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4', '5', '6']).split()))
[12, 3, 456]
```

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain the reasons for the downvote? I would be glad to fix any errors.